# How to add linked file with environment variable in path?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, filepath

I want to add linked files to a project with a environment variable in the path.

When trying with $(SourceLoc)\File.cs, the path is rejected.

When trying with %SourceLoc%\File.cs, the path is accepted but resolved to a full path.

I can close the project and edit the project file manually, add $(SourceLoc) to the path and it work fine. But isn't there any easier way?

**Update**

I found out it could possibly be done with a tool window extensions and DTE. I havn't tested it yet though.

**Update**

I have tried doing this with extensions now but it didn't work either:

```
    Solution2 soln;
    Project prj;
    soln = (Solution2)_dte.Solution;
    ProjectItem prjItem;
    prj = soln.Projects.Item(1);
    prjItem = prj.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(@"%SourcePath%\MyClass.cs"); // fail
    prjItem = prj.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(@"$(SourcePath)\MyClass.cs"); // fail
```

Darnit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio you're adding a file to a project using standard Windows Open File Dialog, thus $(x) doesn work, and %x% is being expanded to the full path.

So no, there is no other way then edit a project file manually.